# Get the incrementing elements of a list

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

I have a list and I am trying to get the elements that are greater from the ones on their left. This is my code:

```
fun incList (hd::h2::tl : int list) = if h2 > hd
                                      then hd::h2::(incList tl)
                                      else hd::(incList tl)
  | incList ([x] : int list) = [x]
  | incList ([] : int list) = []
```

Example:

```
LIST:  [1,5,9,2,88,33,90]
CORRECT RESULT:[1,5,9,88,90]
RETURNS: [1,5,9,2,88,33,90]
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you unhappy with the result? What do you want it to be -- the sublist that starts with 5?

Comment: No it doesn't work. It returns full list

Comment: You should make that part of your question.

Comment: Tangentially: it is more idiomatic to put the empty pattern first, the one with 1 element second and the one with 2 or more elements last. Also, using `hd` as an identifier shadows a built-in function and makes your code harder to read than need be. I would prefer something like `x::y::zs`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my code. It was checking every other character.Now it works:

```
fun incList ([] : int list) = []
        | incList ([x] : int list) = [x]
        | incList (h1::h2::t1 : int list) = if h2>h1 then h1::(incList 
(h2::t1)) else (incList (h1::t1))
```

Comment: By reversing the comparison it will return a list a decrementing elements.